# How would i create a regex for the following

Tags: python, regex

```
some value {arg1} {arg2} {arg3}
another value {arg1}
idkhere {arg1} {arg2}
```

I'm looking to create a regex that will match each {arg\d} as a group, so if theres 3 args in a line it'll have 3 groups, if one then only one group. I'm new to regex so not sure how I'd do this.

Comment: Please be more specific. A code snippet will help.

Comment: I just need help creating a regex that will match all of the {arg<digit>} in a given string. Returning a new group per arg in the string. for example if there was {arg1} {arg2} {arg3} then the regex would return 3 groups

Comment: Groups don't work that way. You probably mean 3 matches? Try this: [`\{arg\d\}`](https://regex101.com/r/Y423LD/1). You can still have each match in a group if you want by using `(\{arg\d\})` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, the number of groups in a regex pattern is pre-determined. If you need to iterate over all the matches, you could do something like this:

```
import re

text = """some value {arg1} {arg2} {arg3}
another value {arg1}
idkhere {arg1} {arg2}"""

pattern = re.compile(r"{arg\d}")

for i in re.findall(pattern, text):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does what I need it to :). Can't mark the answer as valid yet as I have to wait 8 minutes

Comment: @Ryan Glad to help :)